# couchdb Basic authentiation using stdhttpclient

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to get connect to couchdb server using Stdhttpclient (cannot change this as the code was designed using this). I have recently added password security to access Couchdb server. now I am just connecting to it as:

```
stdhttoclient.builder().username().password().url().build;
```

Is there any way to include basic Authentication using stdhttpclient?.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to send encrypted data using Stdhttpclient but In that place I Used Jasypt to encode the Username and password in Property file, decoding them in DAO Class and then sending it over the wire. Not a great solution but it helps to make Property file and User parameters secure.